# Lodash: Swap key with value objects internal attribute

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am getting below JSON response:

```
users: {
    1: {
        name: "John",
        email: "john@test.com",
        id: 1,
        place: "NY"
    },
    2: {
        name: "Alex",
        email: "alex@test.com",
        id: 2,
        place: "FL"
    },
    3: {
        name: "Tony",
        email: "tony@test.com",
        id: 3,
        place: "TX"
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I want to swap the id key with email key from the inner object value as below format.

```
users: {
    "john@test.com": {
        name: "John",
        email: "john@test.com",
        id: 1,
        place: "NY"
    },
}
```

I am using below lodash code to make it work and its working fine:

```
_.keyBy(_.values(data), 'email');
```

Is there a better way I can handle it with lodash? I am new to lodash and I wanted to understand whether the code can be refactored further.

Comment: `lodash` is a javascript library, no need to tag javascript as well. If you're looking for a solution, don't add us javascripters who like vanilla JS solutions for such simple cases. Ask **only** lodash users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `_.keyBy()` accepts a collection (an array or an object), you can skip the `_.values()` call:

```js
const users = {"1":{"name":"John","email":"john@test.com","id":1,"place":"NY"},"2":{"name":"Alex","email":"alex@test.com","id":2,"place":"FL"},"3":{"name":"Tony","email":"tony@test.com","id":3,"place":"TX"}};

const result = _.keyBy(users, 'email');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for Vanilla JavaScript solution you can use [**`array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
users =  {
    1: {
        name: "John",
        email: "john@test.com",
        id: 1,
        place: "NY"
    },
    2: {
        name: "Alex",
        email: "alex@test.com",
        id: 2,
        place: "FL"
    },
    3: {
        name: "Tony",
        email: "tony@test.com",
        id: 3,
        place: "TX"
    }
  }

let newUsers = Object.keys(users).reduce((obj, key) => {
  obj[users[key].email] = users[key];
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(newUsers);
```